# How to round up double to 2 decimal point - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elastic search that looks like :

```
{
                "entityFk": 0,
                "entityCode": "ADM",
                "entityObj": {
                    "id": 0,
                    "code": "ADM",
                    "description": "ADM - FIRSTCOM"
                },
                "practiceFk": 54745,
                "practiceObj": {
                    "id": 54745,
                    "code": "33.04.01.32",
                    "description": "Artrotomia ou artroscopia com tratamento de lesões articulares circunscritas  ",
                    "practiceValue": 23.5
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to sum all "practiceValue" (not null) that has entityCode.description equals to "FIRST", so I made this query :

```
    {
    "size" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : [
                {
                    "missing" : { "field" : "practiceObj.practiceValue" }
                }
             ],
             "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : { "entityObj.description" : "FIRST" }
                }
             ]
         }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "total" : {  
            "sum" : { "field" : "practiceObj.practiceValue"} 

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result I obtained :

```
   {
    "took": 26,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 11477,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1593598.7499999984
        }
    }
}
```

The deal is: how can i round up the value to 2 decimal point.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

EDIT:

here´s my mapping :

```
 {
    "index_practice_entities": {
        "mappings": {
            "practice_entities_search": {
                "properties": {
                    "entityCode": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "entityFk": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "entityObj": {
                        "properties": {
                            "code": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "practiceFk": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "practiceObj": {
                        "properties": {
                            "code": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "description": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "practiceValue": {
                                "type": "double"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please try the below mentioned script, It will round the aggregated value to 2 decimal places.

```
"aggs" : {
        "total" : {  
            "sum" : { 
              "script" : "Math.round(doc['practiceObj.practiceValue'].value*100)/100.0"
               } 

        }
    }
```

Comment: with 100 or 100.0 in the divisor ?

Comment: with the 100.0 divisor

Comment: is this the only way?

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an aggs for managing more precisely the sum of floating point in elastic:

```
{
   "query":{
       /* your's filters */
   },
   "aggs":{
      "price":{
         "sum":{
            "field":"price",
            "script":"BigDecimal.valueOf(_value).setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)",
            "missing":0
         }
      }
   }
}
```

In this example you can manage the scale changing `.setScale` to `2`.

Comment: Hello Manuel, I know you've answered this ages ago, but you're my last glimpse of hope. Can you take a look at this thread and tell me if the problem is solvable? This seems right in your ballpark.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73658743/how-to-round-up-values-in-elasticsearch-query

Answer (score 0):

You can try `script` to achieve this:

```
 "aggs" : {
    "total" : {  
        "sum" : { "script" : "(doc['practiceObj.practiceValue'].value).round(2)"  // practiceValue should be double or float
        } 

    }
}
```

Make sure to [to enable scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html)

Comment: already enabled scripting and didn't wor, still return the same value

Comment: without round "value": 1593598.7499999984

Comment: with round (2) value : 1593598.7499999984

Comment: with round (1) value : 1593671.5000000028

Comment: Using only round() is returning value without decimal.

Comment: I want a return value like "value" : 1593598.75

Comment: can you help me @Richa

Comment: @ sergiogomesdev I am trying ...don't know why is it not working..  Will update my answer ...