# Using the returned value of sum aggregation - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I made this query to sum all my "practiceValue" that are doubles.

```
 {
    "size" : 0,
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must_not" : [
                {
                    "missing" : { "field" : "practiceObj.practiceValue" }
                }
             ],
             "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : { "entityObj.description" : "FIRST" }
                }
             ]
         }
    },
    "aggs" : {
        "total" : {  
            "sum" : { "script" : "(doc['practiceObj.practiceValue'].value)" 
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

My query returned the following:

```
{
    "took": 32,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 11477,
        "max_score": 0,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "total": {
            "value": 1593598.7499999984
        }
    }
}
```

How can I use that "total" value in order to round it?

"value" equals to 1593598.7499999984 and I want to make it 1593598.75

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to round up double to 2 decimal point - elasticsearch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36041812/how-to-round-up-double-to-2-decimal-point-elasticsearch)

Comment: that's my question too, but this one is little different